# Non-interrupting timer boundary event creates multiple tasks

Tags: activiti, bpmn, business-process-management, camunda

I need to create a system that reminds a user 3 times to do a task via email. I added the email class to task listener on assignment.

This step doesn't work because it creates 3 more new tasks. The interrupting timer event doesn't also work  because it cancels the task and the user receives dead links to the task in an email.

I need this to work in a way that only the one instance of the task is running and is canceled only after the 3 loops.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about somethign like this?
Use a regular system task to send email notification called first when the user task is called (parallel gateway).

Then call the same task in timer (repeat twice).
[image]

Hope this helps,
Greg

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is a neat way of doing this. I tried to replicate this using a non-interrupting timer event with cycle (R3/PT15S) but it only works once. It's like the timer event itself gets ended when it gets to the EndEvent. Got any ideas on a workaround?